# Is there a way to get the project folder name only on a Github action?

Tags: github, github-actions

I can get `repoowner/repo-name` with `${{ github.repository }}` but I like to get just the `repo-name`.

While I am at it.

GitLab has a straight forward variable for this.

How do I get reference access env variables from the `.yaml` not inside scripts? Does `${{ $ENV_VAR }}` work? Probably not.

Is there a way to remove or replace the slashes directly in the yaml?

```yaml
  build:
    needs: test
    name: Build release Zip
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      DEPLOY_REF: ${{ github.sha }}
      DEPLOY_REF_SHORT: ${{ github.sha }}
      DEPLOY_ZIPFILE: ${{ github.workspace }}/build/zip/${{ github.repository }}-${{ github.sha }}.zip
    steps:
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`github` context also contains event data, from where you can easily read some more detailed info. In this case, `${{ github.event.repository.name }}` will give you only `repo-name` part.

It might be a good idea to create testing workflow/job to print all context data until you're familiar with them, see [Example printing context information to the log file](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-printing-context-information-to-the-log).

---

As for replacing text, you can always dedicate one of first steps to prepare everything you need later with either [::set-env](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) or [::set-output](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter). You just need to print name/value in specific format, so you can use any shell you're familiar with to manipulate text while doing that:

```yaml
# All steps after this one will have env variable `GHA_BRANCH` passed to them.
- run:   echo ::set-env name=GHA_BRANCH::$(echo $GITHUB_REF | awk -F / '{print $3}')
  shell: bash
```

Comment: Can I use `- run` on a workflow scope? b4 all jobs start? Probably not so I would have to redo it for each job? `::set-env` is good to know.

Comment: @redanimalwar
If N jobs needs same environment tuning, you can keep it all in script file. Just add `- run: ./setup-env.sh` (which will call `echo ::set-env`) as first step of each job - later, any env tuning done in _.sh_ will affect whole workflow.

Comment: Gitlab has a simple `$CI_COMMIT_SLUG` for something like that. Not sure how they get that, maybe I could get something from git itself. What I like is the tag when its a tag build and the branch when its the branch and not a ugly commit hash that says nothing.

Seems annoying to have to dig so deep into that object when I not even know if its always there. I think I am going with that `github.repository` but replacing the `/` with `-` because this will not play nice with filenames. I may actually only need it in one job for now.

Comment: `${{ github.event.repository.name }}` did not work for me, at least not under `env`; it was the empty string/not defined. `${{ github.repository_owner }}` worked though (but doesn't solve the problem, of course).

Comment: This will not work for actions scheduled via cron. The event payload is empty.

Comment: >  see Example printing context information to the log file.

- the link is broken. See this link instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/72920652/723891

Comment: Now info is available for actions scheduled via cron as well.  See https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-27-github-actions-additional-information-available-in-github-event-payload-for-scheduled-workflow-runs/

Comment: Works like a charm, you don't need any extra packages for getting repo's name.

Answer (score 24):

In addition to @Samira response, you could also use `${GITHUB_REPOSITORY#*/}` to get the repository name, since it will cut all before the `/` prefix.

For e.g., at my workflow I use:

```
- run: echo ::set-env name=TF_VAR_instance_label::${GITHUB_REPOSITORY#*/}-${GITHUB_SHA:0:7}
```

Comment: New bash shell users could find the hash sign (#) in [Bash Reference Manual § 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).