# Echo Github Action Environment variables

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to dive in the GitHub Action, and to understand the process I would like to echo some environment variables, such as `${{ github.repository }}`, `${{ github.repository_owner }}` or event secrets like `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}`, etc. But then in the output I'm getting `***`.

Is there any way to force the output to show the actual values instead of the asterisks?

> dev.yml

```
name: Dev

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev

env:
  BUILD_TYPE: core
  DEFAULT_PYTHON: 3.8

jobs:
  any_name:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Any Name Bash Test Step
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "GH_REPO: $GH_REPO"
          echo "GH_REPO_O: $GH_REPO_O"
          echo "GH_T: $GH_T"
        env:
          GH_REPO: ${{ github.repository }}
          GH_REPO_O: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          GH_T: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

> output

```
Run echo "GH_REPO: $GH_REPO"
  echo "GH_REPO_O: $GH_REPO_O"
  echo "GH_T: $GH_T"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
  env:
    BUILD_TYPE: core
    DEFAULT_PYTHON: 3.8
    GH_REPO: ***/core
    GH_REPO_O: ***
    GH_T: ***
GH_REPO: ***/core
GH_REPO_O: ***
GH_T: ***
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't show `secrets` through `echo` otherwise there would be a huge security problem (even using `env` variables as an intermediary).

However, this will work with the other variables you used, the problem in your case seems to be related to the syntax. You should use run: `echo "$GITHUB_REPOSITORY"` and `run: echo "$GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER"` to see them directly on your workflow.

*Note: `${{ github.repository }}` or `${{ github.repository_owner }}` also works.*

---

**Tip:** You can identify most of the variables that can be shown with echo through the [Github Context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context) using  `run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"` in your workflow.

**Example:**

[image: Example]

[Picture Reference](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/open-issue-action/runs/2556548432?check_suite_focus=true)

Comment: The answer and the tip was very useful and solve my issue, more than that following the link to the doc, I've found Example printing context information to the log file (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#example-printing-context-information-to-the-log-file) who show I guess all the variables. Thanks!

Comment: This is not working anymore

Comment: What did you try to do that is not working anymore @Matteo?

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong, I just insert this `run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"` into my pipeline, it just echos the string `"$GITHUB_CONTEXT"`, instead using the link drypatrick provided it does work

Comment: Did you use the `env: GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJSON(github) }}` at the step level as well? It may not work without it (as shown in the link *drypatrick* shared above).

Comment: You can use: `run: echo '${{ toJSON(github) }}'` to dump the context.

Comment: @T3rm1 its still prints asteriks

Comment: Asterisks appear if you're trying to echo a secret value. Did you add a secret value to your GITHUB_CONTEXT somewhere?

Comment: "huge security problem" is making many assumptions.

Comment: @GuiFalourd: In `$GITHUB.REPOSITORY` and `$GITHUB.REPOSITORY_OWNER`, the dot doesn't seem to be correct, it should be an underscore. You might want to fix those. Reference: [Default environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, both should work @Azeem. `$GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER` and `$GITHUB_REPOSITORY` are equivalent to `${{ github.repository }}` and `${{ github.repository_owner }}`, aren't they?

Comment: @GuiFalourd: Your above comment is correct. But, in your answer, `echo "$GITHUB.REPOSITORY"` and `echo "$GITHUB.REPOSITORY_OWNER"` under `run` are not correct. There's a dot in there and it is under shell.

Answer (score 45):

```
name: This is an example

on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  one:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Dump GitHub context
        env:
          GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}
        run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
      - name: Dump job context
        env:
          JOB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(job) }}
        run: echo "$JOB_CONTEXT"
      - name: Dump steps context
        env:
          STEPS_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(steps) }}
        run: echo "$STEPS_CONTEXT"
      - name: Dump runner context
        env:
          RUNNER_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(runner) }}
        run: echo "$RUNNER_CONTEXT"
      - name: Dump strategy context
        env:
          STRATEGY_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(strategy) }}
        run: echo "$STRATEGY_CONTEXT"
      - name: Dump matrix context
        env:
          MATRIX_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(matrix) }}
        run: echo "$MATRIX_CONTEXT"

      - name: Show default environment variables
        run: |
          echo "The job_id is: $GITHUB_JOB"   # reference the default environment variables
          echo "The id of this action is: $GITHUB_ACTION"   # reference the default environment variables
          echo "The run id is: $GITHUB_RUN_ID"
          echo "The GitHub Actor's username is: $GITHUB_ACTOR"
          echo "GitHub SHA: $GITHUB_SHA"
```

Comment: As other answer explain, it can work properly. Also, can you [edit] your post to add details and explain?

Answer (score 7):

If variable are print as `***` (mostly for secrets variables), you can use script that put result in file, and upload file to artifact, like that:

```yaml
name: "Save secrets variables"

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  one:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: "Echo in file"
      env:
        SECRETS_VARS: ${{ toJson(secrets) }}
      run: echo "$SECRETS_VARS" > "secrets.txt"
      
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      name: Upload Artifact
      with:
        name: SecretsVariables
        path: "secrets.txt"
```